# How to toggle between two recently selected windows using Alt-Tab in Enlightenment WM (0.19.2)

Tags: enlightenment

Is it even possible?

Here's how to reproduce:

1. Open more than two applications.
2. Use the mouse to select any window.
3. Use the mouse again to select a different window.
4. Hit Alt-Tab (the first window is selected).
5. Hit Alt-Tab again (a third window is selected).

I'd like step 5 to return to the first window.

Note:
[Enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlightenment_%28software%29) is windows manager (WM) for the X Windows System.

Comment: idk if it works for that app, but usually it's [key]+tab to go one way [key]+shift+tab to go the other.

Answer (score 0):

Like most things in enlightenment there is a setting for that.

go to "Settings Panel->Windows (Tab)->Window List Menu->Sort Order(Tab)" Then select "Most recently used" and hit apply

If this doesn't work its likely a bug in enlightenment.